# Manipulação de caracteres em PHP

Tags: php

Exemplo, nós recebemos um login dessa forma

```
joao.silvestre
```

E eu quero pegar a cadeia de caracteres com a seguinte regra:

A primeira letra do nome + as 7 letras que vem depois do ponto que separa o nome do sobrenome, por exemplo:

```
jsilvest
```

Como faço para capturar essa cadeia seguindo as regras acima em PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, partindo do princípio que vai sempre haver um ponto entre os nomes:

```
$username = 'joao.silvestre';
$names = explode('.', $username);
$final = $names[0][0].substr($names[1], 0, 7); // no segundo nome vamos extrair os caracteres a começar no indice 0 até termos 7 caracteres
echo $final; // jsilvest
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/GeJ84e)

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou certinho :) Muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada @RafaelBrito

Comment: . . tempo: 6.9μs

Answer (score 2):

> Isso é uma variação da resposta do @Miguel:

Você pode usar isso:

```
$nome  = 'joao.silvestre';
$final = $nome[0].substr(explode('.', $nome)[1], 0, 7);
```

*[Isso funciona](http://ideone.com/j6zu43) em PHP 5.5 e superior, salvo engano.*

Comment: . .   tempo: 6.9μs

Answer (score 1):

Opção com REGEX

```
$str = 'joao.silvestre';
preg_match('/[^.][\w]{6}/', $str, $rs);
echo $str[0].$rs[0];
```

Tempo: 0.00000905990600585938 (9μs)